# Akka Http Segment in the route path is not working as expected

Tags: akka-http

I have akka http app running using the code [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/akka_in_action/blob/master/chapter2/src/main/scala/app/Main.scala) and one of my [routes](https://github.com/rajcspsg/akka_in_action/blob/master/chapter2/src/main/scala/rest/RestRoutes.scala#L68) is having segments in it.

When I tested the rest path with segment, I get the below error.

**Request**

curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d \
'{"tickets":2}' \
 'http://localhost:5000/events/RHCP/tickets'

**Response**

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Content-Length: 83

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2018 11:59:38 GMT

Server: GoTicks.com REST API

The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future.

Is there any configuration missing or it is bug?

Comment: It's your code that is returning 404 here https://github.com/rajcspsg/akka_in_action/blob/master/chapter1/src/main/scala/rest/RestRoutes.scala#L58. This is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think pathPrefix is matching eventsRoute and finds no POST directive

try this:

change

```
def routes: Route = eventRoute ~ eventsRoute ~ ticketsRoute
```

to

```
def routes: Route = ticketsRoute ~ eventsRoute ~ eventRoute
```